# Get rid of car lease in an emergency situation

Tags: united-states, car, auto-leasing

One of my friends leased a car 5 months ago from Acura with a 36 month lease. She has a emergency situation and she might have to go back home (North Africa) in 2-3 months.
Apart from using Swapalease or such platforms to transfer the lease to another person (she is not sure if Acura lets her do that), do you think there is a way she can return the car to Acura?

I know this place might not be the best place to ask such question but I could not find any other place and she was so frustrated that I wanted to help her.

She lives in the US.

Answer (score 2):

In the abstract you have two options:  the first is to have someone take over the lease, the second to have the company take back the car.

You can either use "Swapalease or such platforms" in the first case, or you can find someone on your own.  Finding someone can be difficult.  A slight modification to this plan is to buy out the lease and sell the car.

In the second case, she can turn the car in or just stop making the payment.  Either way the company will take the car back and it will result in a negative mark on her credit.

What is preventing this friend from continuing to make the payments and to leave the car with a trusted friend?  A buddy who was deployed did this with his motorcycle and I rode it once a month while he was out of the country.

Its just another reason not to buy a car with a loan or lease.

Comment: A good answer except for your last sentence. Judgement is not necessary - you don't know this persons personal situation at all.